# Help me understand making maven project w/ non-maven jar dependencies usable by others

Tags: java, maven-2, dependencies, open-source

I'm in the process of learning maven (and java packaging & distribution) with a new oss project I'm making as practice. Here's my situation, all java of course:

My main project is ProjectA, maven-based in a github repository. I have also created one utility project, maven-based, in github: ProjectB. ProjectA depends on a project I have heavily modified that originally was from a google-code ant-based repository, ProjectC.

So, how do I set up the build for ProjectA such that someone can download ProjectA.jar and use it without needing to install jars for ProjectB and ProjectC, and also how do I set up the build such that someone could check out ProjectA and run *only* 'mvn package' for a full compile?

(Additionally, what should I do with my modified version of ProjectC? include the class files directly into ProjectA, or fork the project into something that could then be used by as a maven dependency?)

I've been reading around, links such as [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229757/maven-add-a-dependency-to-a-jar-by-relative-path) and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621099/integrating-maven-non-maven-projects), but I'm unclear how those relate to my particular circumstance. So, any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, how do I set up the build for ProjectA such that someone can download ProjectA.jar and use it without needing to install jars for ProjectB and ProjectC

Assuming ProjectA is a JAR, you can create an executable JAR that bundles the dependencies with the [Maven Assembly Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) (and the predefined [`jar-with-dependencies`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor-refs.html#jar-with-dependencies) descriptor) or with the [Maven Shade Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/).

> how do I set up the build such that someone could check out ProjectA and run only 'mvn package' for a full compile?

You have to `deploy` the dependencies to a repository that can be read over HTTP  and to declare this repository in your pom.xml. AFAIK, git-hub doesn't offer any facility for that. But any web hosting service with [FTP](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/examples/deploy-ftp.html) access (or better, scp) should do the trick. If your project is open source, another option would be to use Sonatype's [OSS Repository Hosting](http://nexus.sonatype.org/oss-repository-hosting.html) service.

Just in case, you might want to read [this blog post](http://www.owengriffin.com/posts/2010/04/15/Releasing_Maven_projects_to_Github.html) but you won't learn much more things.

The easiest would still be to organize the 3 projects as a multi-modules maven project and to build all modules.

> Additionally, what should I do with my modified version of ProjectC?

From a modularization point of view (assuming you found a solution for the above part about repository), it would certainly make sense to have it as a separate module, especially if there is an opportunity someone can use ProjectC outside your project.

Comment: Thank you! I'll look into those resources.

Answer (score 1):

You have to publish the code from the additional dependencies. Two options:

1. Use the maven-shade-plugin to create a maven artifact containing all the content of the B and C jars, and publish that under your own G/A/V coordinates.
2. Publish copies of B and C under your own G/A/V coordinates using the maven-deploy-plugin to your forge just as you will publish your own code. Different forges have different policies; but if you abide by the licenses of B and C you should be OK.