# How to wrap an Ant v.1.8.1 build with Maven v. 2.x?

Tags: ant, maven-2

I need to build project with subprojects and main project is the Maven project, one of the subprojects - is the Ant project.
I need to compile all projects from one main pom.xml
I have found solution [How to wrap an Ant build with Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456901/how-to-wrap-an-ant-build-with-maven) and it's answer is correct, but not for my project. Because when my ant project required Ant v. 1.8.x, but on build with the

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ant-contrib</groupId>
            <artifactId>ant-contrib</artifactId>
            <version>1.0b3</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ant</groupId>
                    <artifactId>ant</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
            <artifactId>ant-nodeps</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <modules>
        <module>Bundles/I_AboutForm</module>
        <module>Bundles/I_AppVars</module>
    </modules>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <!--<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml" classpathref="maven.plugin.classpath" />-->
                            <tasks>
                                <ant antfile="MainApplication/build.xml" target="compile"/>
                            </tasks>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

maven downloaded Ant v. 1.7.1 and uses him on build (in the local repo has Ant v.1.8.1).
I think, may be trouble in the dependings of the ant-contrib 1.0b3 - may be ant-contrib depends on Ant v. 1.7.1?

Please advice me how to build Ant v. 1.8.x project in Maven.
Thanks, best regards, Arthur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looking at the version of the plugin 1.7, it seems to use the ant version 1.8.2
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/dependencies.html

Try to specify the version 1.7 of the plugin maven-antrun-plugin

for example:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
```