# Maven default compile not picking up custom plugin goal

Tags: maven-plugin

I have written a custom plugin, then I installed it. Then I modified the `pom.xml` of the project from which I want to use the custom plugin.  When I invoke my plugin goal directly the plugin goal is executed successfully, but when I try to `mvn compile` my custom plugin goal is not executed.  What might be the reason?

My plugin's `pom.xml`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.xxx.plugins.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>datanucleus-enhance-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Datanucleus-enhance Maven Plugin</name>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-tools</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-plugin-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

My project using custom plugin I added following:

```
    <!-- enhance JDO classes -->
    <plugin>
      <groupId>com.sukantu.plugins.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>datanucleus-enhance-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <configuration>
        <jdoClassDirList>
          <param>target/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}/WEB-INF/classes/</param>
        </jdoClassDirList>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>enhance</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

I followed section *Attaching the Mojo to the Build Lifecycle* from maven guide site: https://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html

The following command successfully calls my plugin goal:
`mvn com.xxx.plugins.maven:datanucleus-enhance-maven-plugin:enhance`

The following command does NOT successfully call my plugin goal:
`mvn compile`

Thanks for any inputs!

Comment: Where did you define the plugin configuration? <build>/<plugins> or <build>/<pluginManagement>?

Comment: I was trying with pluginManagement earlier, but later found how to resolve this issue.  Please see answer I posted.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I came across this link:
[How do I link a plugin execution to a phase in maven without forcing me to specify plugin on command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1810430/how-do-i-link-a-plugin-execution-to-a-phase-in-maven-without-forcing-me-to-speci?rq=1)

So I removed `<pluginManagement>` tags so `<plugins>` appear directly under '`<build>`'.  Then I tried '`mvn compile`' from command line and it successfully called my custom plugin goal!

But when I checked pom.xml in Eclipse I saw another error referenced here [How to solve “Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352208/how-to-solve-plugin-execution-not-covered-by-lifecycle-configuration-for-sprin) .

Since the command line is working correctly, I think this is m2e Eclipse plugin error and so I have disabled the marked by going to 'Eclipse' -> 'Window' -> 'Show View' -> 'Markers' -> right click that marker -> 'Delete'.  Now Eclipse is not showing any error and command line is also working as expected.  Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Awsome this fixed the issue for me