# Using ant's loggers and listeners with maven-antrun-plugin

Tags: maven, ant, maven-antrun-plugin

I would like to use the ant org.apache.tools.ant.listener.ProfileLogger inside of my maven-antrun-plugin executions.

Is this possible?

Any other ways of profiling how long my ant tasks/targets are taking to run when run inside of Maven?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to time the different stages of maven execution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120470/how-to-time-the-different-stages-of-maven-execution)