# Profiling Maven Compilation for a multi-module project

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I have a multi module maven project which is taking a little too much time. Can some one let me know if there is a way it is possible for me to see which step in maven compilation is taking how much time. Also is it possible to see which steps are getting executed in parallel relative to which step?

I am executing maven like below:-

```
mvn clean install -T 4
```

- Maven Version 3.5.0

Comment: This should answer the first question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120470/how-to-time-the-different-stages-of-maven-execution .

Comment: Thanks https://github.com/jcgay/maven-profiler worked fine for me in providing the compilation time. Is there a way I can also which steps are getting executed in parallel relative to which step?

Comment: I don't know. It is generally not a good idea to ask two questions at once on Stack Overflow, you should split them up.

Comment: Actually I asked this question as profiling for the entire maven execution consisting of time as well as thread information.